# Homology of a space with fundamental group $S_{3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am currently self studying algebraic topology and I am stuck in the following problem. Let X be a space such that $\pi_{1}(X) = S_{3} $ the symmetric group n = 3, with 3 2-cells, 2 1-cells and 1 0-cell. Calculate the homology groups with integers coefficients. My attempt was the following, using cellular homology we have

$$ 0 \to \mathbb{Z}^3 \xrightarrow{d_2}  \mathbb{Z}^2 \xrightarrow{d_1} \mathbb{Z} \to 0 $$

We also know the presentation of $S_{3}$, so $\pi_{1}(X) = \langle a, b \mid a^2, b^2, (ab)^3 \rangle $, so we have $H_{0}(X) = \mathbb{Z}$, since $H_{1}(X)$ is isomorphic to the abelianization of $S_{3}$ we have $H_{1}(X) = Z/2$. So this implies that $d_{2}$ is the multiplication by two, but this is where I am stuck, I cannot see why this is the case, the only thing I have in mind is that it sends $a$ to $2a$ and b to $2b$. Also I am having trouble seeing the kernel of $d_{2}$. Any help or any tip regarding this ? thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After choosing bases for $\mathbb{Z}^3$ and $\mathbb{Z}^2$, $d_2$ is represented by a $2 \times 3$ matrix. (So it is not "multiplication by 2," and it doesn't send $a$ anywhere: $a$ lives in $\pi_1(X)$, not in $C_2(X)$.) Because you know that $H_1(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$, you know that you can choose bases so that the image of $d_2$ in $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{Z} \oplus 2 \mathbb{Z}$.

Now what can you say about the rank of the matrix representing $d_2$?

> The rank must be 2, so its nullity is 1, so you can identify the kernel:

> The kernel is a free abelian group of rank 1 in $\mathbb{Z}^3$: that is, $\ker d_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}$. Since there are no boundaries in dimension 2, $H_2(X) = \ker d_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Amazing! now I get it, thank you very much.